# connect to mysql with c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

how can i connect with MySql in app?and what software,i must install for mysql?thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use MySQL connector: [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), everything you need you'll find on [tutorials page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: heh, I was 37 seconds too late :)