# Displaying mysql table with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I want to display a table from an mysql Db with asp.net.
What do you suggest is the best way to to this?

I'm new to mysql with asp.net so i have no idea.

Comment: meh I should have checked. There are answers already here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448351/connect-to-mysql-with-c-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can download the providers from the below url:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.0.html

Install it on your machine. And in your project add the appropriate reference. Import the namespace in your code. YOu'll be able to use objects which talk with mysql server. Look at sample below:

http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson02.htm